# Returning rows between specified date columns

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

```
MatchDate   ColA    ColB    PossibleDate
01/01/2012  ABC     123     01/01/2012
01/01/2012  ABC     123     09/01/2012
01/01/2012  ABC     123     01/15/2013
09/01/2012  ABC     123     01/01/2012
09/01/2012  ABC     123     09/01/2012
09/01/2012  ABC     123     09/13/2012
09/01/2012  ABC     123     10/11/2012
09/01/2012  ABC     123     01/15/2013
01/15/2013  ABC     123     01/01/2012
01/15/2013  ABC     123     09/01/2012
01/15/2013  ABC     123     01/15/2013
01/15/2013  ABC     123     02/22/2013
08/15/2012  XYZ     777     08/15/2012
08/15/2012  XYZ     777     08/28/2012
08/15/2012  XYZ     777     10/11/2012
08/15/2012  XYZ     777     01/15/2013
01/15/2013  XYZ     777     01/15/2013
01/15/2013  XYZ     777     08/15/2012
```

The results I'm looking for:

```
MatchDate   ColA    ColB    PossibleDate
01/01/2012  ABC     123     NULL
09/01/2012  ABC     123     09/13/2012
09/01/2012  ABC     123     10/11/2012
01/15/2013  ABC     123     02/22/2013
08/15/2012  XYZ     777     08/28/2012
08/15/2012  XYZ     777     10/11/2012
01/15/2013  XYZ     777     NULL
```

It should return rows for each unique "MatchDate, ColA, and ColB" columns and any "possible date" that falls in between the MatchDate and PossibleDate.

I've added notes to explain why each column would be valid and why it would not:

```
 MatchDate  ColA    ColB    PossibleDate    (Notes)
01/01/2012  ABC     123     01/01/2012      (Not valid as it's MatchDate already exists for "ABC, 123")
01/01/2012  ABC     123     09/01/2012      (Not valid as it's MatchDate already exists for "ABC, 123")
01/01/2012  ABC     123     01/15/2013      (Not valid as it's MatchDate already exists for "ABC, 123")
09/01/2012  ABC     123     01/01/2012      (Not valid as it's MatchDate already exists for "ABC, 123")
09/01/2012  ABC     123     09/01/2012      (Not valid as it's MatchDate already exists for "ABC, 123")
09/01/2012  ABC     123     09/13/2012      (VALID as it's PossibleDate is NOT a MatchDate and it's between 09/01/2012 and the next possible MatchDate of 01/15/2013 for "ABC, 123")
09/01/2012  ABC     123     10/11/2012      (VALID as it's PossibleDate is NOT a MatchDate and it's between 09/01/2012 and the next possible MatchDate of 01/15/2013 for "ABC, 123")
09/01/2012  ABC     123     01/15/2013      (Not valid as it's MatchDate already exists for "ABC, 123")
01/15/2013  ABC     123     01/01/2012      (Not valid as it's MatchDate already exists for "ABC, 123")
01/15/2013  ABC     123     09/01/2012      (Not valid as it's MatchDate already exists for "ABC, 123")
01/15/2013  ABC     123     01/15/2013      (Not valid as it's MatchDate already exists for "ABC, 123")
01/15/2013  ABC     123     02/22/2013      (VALID as it's PossibleDate is NOT a MatchDate and it's between 01/15/2013 and the next possible MatchDate, which doesn't exist as it's the largest MatchDate for "ABC, 123")
08/15/2012  XYZ     777     08/15/2012      (Not valid as it's MatchDate already exists for "XYZ, 777")
08/15/2012  XYZ     777     08/28/2012      (VALID as it's PossibleDate is NOT a MatchDate and it's between 08/15/2012 and the next possible MatchDate of 01/15/2013 for "XYZ, 777")
08/15/2012  XYZ     777     10/11/2012      (VALID as it's PossibleDate is NOT a MatchDate and it's between 08/15/2012 and the next possible MatchDate of 01/15/2013 for "XYZ, 777")
08/15/2012  XYZ     777     01/15/2013      (Not valid as it's MatchDate already exists for "XYZ, 777")
01/15/2013  XYZ     777     01/15/2013      (Not valid as it's MatchDate already exists for "XYZ, 777")
01/15/2013  XYZ     777     08/15/2012      (VALID as it's PossibleDate is NOT a MatchDate and it's between 01/15/2013 and the next possible MatchDate, which doesn't exist as it's the largest MatchDate for "XYZ, 777")
```

Thanks in advance...hope it's not too confusing.

Comment: All kidding (and aspirin) aside, I think you're going to have to explain your search protocol a bit more plainly to get any help, or I suspect you risk getting the question closed...I've tried a few times to unwind what you're asking and I'm just not getting there...sorry :(

Comment: Sorry, I attempted to explain why each column is valid.  Basically for a given group, I need all the rows between two specific dates.  The problem is that the date that it needs to compare it to MAY be in the next row.

Comment: Ugh...any time you start looking at sets of SQL data and then talk about what might be in the "next" row, you've just made writing a query drastically less pleasant. Hope someone else can help you, because I'm just not smart enough to infer your general rule(s) from just the results you've listed. Thanks for trying, sorry I can't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if I understand all, please try this.

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/09a9f/8)

```
WITH cte AS
(SELECT *, 
   NexMatchDate = ISNULL(
       (SELECT MIN(MatchDate) 
        FROM t t2 
        WHERE t2.MatchDate > t.MatchDate
         AND t2.ColA = t.ColA AND t2.ColB = t.ColB)
     ,'99991231')
 FROM t
)
, datelist AS
(SELECT DISTINCT MatchDate, ColA, ColB
 FROM t
)
SELECT d.MatchDate, d.ColA, d.ColB, c.PossibleDate
from datelist d
LEFT JOIN cte c
  ON d.MatchDate = c.MatchDate
  AND d.ColA = c.ColA
  AND d.ColB = c.ColB
  AND c.PossibleDate > c.MatchDate AND c.PossibleDate < c.NexMatchDate
ORDER BY 1,2,3
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Sorry that the scope was too narrow, but I'm certain others can use this.